# How to check java application status (Running or stopped) running on a windows server

Tags: java, windows-server-2012-r2, application-state

I have a java jar running on windows server 2012 r2. I have created a task to run this jar on every restart of the server. Now, I need to restart the application whenever its stopped because of some reason. So I should find a way to find the status of the application.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to handle problems of this sort is with a service wrapper application, of which there are many, each with particular features. Popular examples include
[Tanuki](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp), [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/), and [Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html), among others. These wrappers have built-in facilities to monitor and keep alive the applications they govern.

If you just want to check whether the application is running, then a common approach is to send probes to some TCP port that it exposes. Many applications open a port specifically for this purpose.